# Sourcing shell scripts in Perl

Tags: perl, shell

I want to source a shell script from within Perl and have the environment variables be available in Perl, but I'm not sure if there's an elegant way to do it. Obviously, using [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) won't work since it runs in a forked process, and all environment changes will be lost. I think there's a CPAN module that can do it, but I prefer not to use external modules.

I've seen two solutions that would not work in my case:

1. Have a wrapper that calls the shell script, and then calls the Perl script. I do not know ahead of time which of my shell scripts I need to call.
2. Manually opening the shell script and scraping for `arg=value` pairs. This won't work either because the shell script is not a simple list of `ARG=VALUE`, but rather contain a bunch of conditionals, and variables can have different values depending on certain conditions.

Comment: Didn't realize until just now that I had to click a button to indicate an answer was useful.

Comment: There's another checkmark-shaped button you should click to indicate your choice for the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sh -c "source script; env"` should output the environment at the end of script as name=value pairs, which you then can parse from your perl script (as Perl is a language made for parsing, this should be easy).

Comment: Even if you can't touch the scripts, running `sh -c "source somescript; env"` should be workable.

Comment: Oh, this is a perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: @hobbs: Thanks for the idea, I edited my answer to include this instead (for easier reference later).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by installing external module from CPAN which is Shell::Source

```
$env_path= Shell::Source->new(shell=>"tcsh",file=>"../path/to/file/temp.csh");
$env_path->inherit;
```

As perl creates its own instance while running on a shell, so we can not set environment path for the main shell as the perl's instance will be like sub shell of the main shell. Child can not set environment paths for parents.

Now till the perl's sub shell will run you'll be able to access all the paths present in temp.csh by using Shell::Source